# How to define fields in an AbstractIndexCreationTask?

Tags: ravendb

I've got an `AbstractIndexCreationTask` in my application as follows:

```
public class EventsForMainQueries : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Event>
{
    public EventsForMainQueries()
    {
        Map = docs => from doc in docs
                      select new
                      {
                          DatePublished = doc.DatePublished,
                          IsDeleted     = doc.IsDeleted,
                          Author        = doc.Author,
                          EventDate     = doc.EventDate
                      };

        Index(x => x.DatePublished, FieldIndexing.Default);
        Sort(x => x.DatePublished, SortOptions.String);

        Index(x => x.EventDate, FieldIndexing.Default);
        Sort(x => x.EventDate, SortOptions.String);
    }
}
```

however, RavenDB is still creating the following auto index.

[image: Temp index created by RavenDB]

What do I need to change in my IndexCreationTask to prevent the temp/auto index being generated?

Comment: Temp indexes are crated in response to queries that don't specify an index.  What query(s) do you make?

Comment: @MattJohnson as per the index name, I queried by `EventDate:[ ... ] AND IsDeleted:...` and ordered by EventDate. Without the order by, my index is used, adding the order by creates the temp index wih the field. So how do I define an index in code such that the settings we see in the image for the EventDate field are replicated in code?

Comment: @GregB assuming doc.EventDate is DateTime I don't think you need to do anything. Also I don't think you ever need to do Index(date). I have zero usages of Index/Sort relating to dates. The only time i ever use Index is for (FieldIndexing.Analyzed). I do use Store() alot. I stream results from indexes and don't bring back full documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ever call `IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(EventsForMainQueries).Assembly, documentStore);` or in any other way create that index on the server?

You can also "force" which index you're reading from by using:

`session.Query<Event, EventsForMainQueries>()....`

If your index is not on the server, this query should error not create a temp index.

Comment: Specifying the index has worked, but I thought RavenDB checked if it had an index it can use to fulfil the query before creating a temp index?

Comment: @GregB I don't specifically see any reason it should need to have created that auto index. One thing to note if EventDate is a DateTime or DateTimeOffset if you use Sort.Text you will not get correct sorting as it will be sorted lexically and not as dates.

Comment: thanks, what is the correct sorting to use for a `DateTime` field?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Storing the index:

```
EventsForMainQueries.Execute(DocumentStore);
```

Quering the events:

```
Session.Query<Event, EventsForMainQueries>()
```